# Not understanding how k-means clustering or Lloyd's Algorithm Updates

Tags: euclidean-geometry, voronoi-diagram

I’m not understanding how k-means clustering updates. 
At time t=0, all samples are grouped to the random initialization centroids.
Next the means of all samples pertaining to each centroid is calculated, and each centroid is moved to its (new) mean location.
I’m not understanding why that (new) mean location would be different than the original position for a continuous space. 
Particularly, I'm looking at Assignment Step and Update Step here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: Calculate the centroids. Now forget which points are assigned to which clusters. Go through each point & calculate which centroid it is closest to & assign it to that cluster. Repeat until the points no longer change their cluster.

Answer (score 1):

This image (from [here](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/tag/lloyds-algorithm/)) gives an animation that hopefully makes this clearer:

[image: k-means animation]

After the centroids are moved (the stars moving), the Voronoi diagram is recomputed, changing which centroid the sample points are associated with. In this image, that is seen as the recoloring of the circles (which happens in between moving the starts/centroids).